# Ingress rule cannot resolve the backend server ip address on Azure AKS

Tags: azure, nginx, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I installed the ingress controller on my aks using the helm install. I also created an ingress rule for my service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-demo-ingress
  namespace: my-demo
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: mydemoingress.com 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-gateway
            port: 
              number: 8080
```

When I deployed above ingress rule, i notice that my Backends has no IP as seen below api-gateway:8080 **()**:

```
**kubectl describe ing my-demo-ingress -n my-demo**
Name:             my-demo-ingress
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
Namespace:        my-demo
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host            Path  Backends
  ----            ----  --------
  mydemoingress.com  
                  /(.*)   **api-gateway:8080 (<none>)**
Annotations:     
                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: false
                  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age    From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----   ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    4m34s  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    4m34s  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

No IP address gets assigned to the ingress controller.

When i however try this same setup on my local k3s setup, the IP is assigned correctly. Please what am i doing wrong?

**Update: Helm install command for ingress controller:**

```
NAMESPACE=ingress-basic

helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update

helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
  --create-namespace \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE \
  --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz
```

Comment: Can you share the `helm install` command for the ingress controller?

Comment: Updated to include the helm install command

Answer (score 0):

•   AFAIK, the syntax used for the **‘servicePort’** and the **‘serviceName’** should be as per given in the below sample **‘YAML’** file. Also, the **path to the specified service name might be missing** as per the YAML file that you have shared due to which while provisioning the service in the AKS cluster, the **port mapping might not be correct and hence, the internal load balancer could not reach out to the created service**.

Sample YAML file: -

```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: hello-world-ingress
      namespace: ingress-basic
      annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
 spec:
 rules:
 - http:
  paths:
  - backend:
      serviceName: aks-helloworld
      servicePort: 80
    path: /(.*)
  - backend:
      serviceName: ingress-demo
      servicePort: 80
    path: /hello-world-two(/|$)(.*)
```

•   Thus, apart from the above-stated modifications, I would also suggest you to please check whether you have **assigned an IP address that is not in use in your virtual network and that you have deployed a load balancer using that IP address in AKS cluster** as below: -

```
   controller:
    service:
     loadBalancerIP: 10.240.0.42
      annotations:
       service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

These modifications should help you resolve your issue with the backend IP address pools.

Also, do refer the below link for more information: -

https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip253.html

Comment: Hi @IgbeChukwudi, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.